# Desktop doesn't login after GDM login unless I restart it

Tags: gnome

from a couple of days I'm having a problem with Gnome3 gnome-shell. When I reboot / power-on the machine, after the GDM login the DE is stuck without opening gnome-shell. If I restart gdm from another tty, then everything works (GDM restarts and gnome-shell appears). So it hangs only the first time i login.

I was looking for more information on what is happening, but I can't find a gdm or gnome-shell detailed log. any suggestions?

Currently using Gnome3 PPA + ([ricotz PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing)) + ATI open source drivers

Comment: I thought that the Ricotz GNOME 3 PPA had stopped being updated way back during GNOME 3's development? Or did something about that change and I didn't notice since I was just compiling everything from GNOME's git repos?

Comment: Actually it's up-to-date and is the only one with the latest gnome-shell package.

Comment: And why are you using both the Gnome 3 team PPA and the ricotz PPA?, shouldn't you be using only one?

Comment: Gnome3ppa gives me "quite stable" packages, and riotz gives me the latest gnome-shell and network-manager.

Comment: Anyway, they are compatible, and gnome3ppa is required by ricotz, as you can see in his launchpad dedicated page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have the same problem in natty with Unity not booting in but after I took the plunge and installed the ATI fglrx drivers the problem disappeared completly. 
Not sure if that would help you with gnome 3 but it might be worth a try

I did it using the terminal with the

*sudo apt-get install fglrx*

For some reason I do not understand it fixed my login issues issues and I was having exactly the same issue as you ie I would have to log in again to get a desktop which was (as you are finding ) a little annoying.

I would have preferred to stick with the open source drivers and do not do any 3d stuff to speak of but as this fix worked for me I stuck with it.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: GNOME3 is not compatible with fglrx in my installation, I had to remove it to make GNOME3 work.... but your answer helped me solving the problem. Actually, I had installed fglrx on the machine, later uninstalled it and switched to open-source drivers. For some reason, X was still trying to load fglrx module and reported the MISS in Xorg.conf. `sudo update-alternatives --config gl_conf` and setting to Auto solved the problem and now gnome-shell is working perfectly, without login issues.

Comment: yippee! :) Might be worth checking here to make sure fglrx is completely purged. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch

Comment: [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1725375) is a good link too :)

Comment: hmm...not seen that one.will now have a read and learn more...cheers :)  I did try gnome shell etc when it was a seperate ppa for 11.04. It crashed and had to reinstall most of unity which was a pain but I have heard it works fine now...is it good?

Comment: Actually it's working very well :) Personally I prefer gnome-shell to unity but it's a matter of personal taste